# Why can I not connect to the mongoose server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-web-server

I have implemented the code below in a db.js  file to require mongoose and connect to the mongoose server. The code is below which is in a db.js file

```
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );
var dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost/CaribbeanDb';
mongoose.connect(dbURI);

mongoose.connection.on('connected', function (){
console.log('Mongoose connected to ' + dbUEI); 
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err){
console.log('Mongoose connection error:' + err); 
});
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function (){
console.log('Mongoose disconnected:'); 
});
```

I will get this error when I try to connect to mongoose

```
node:16880) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
Mongoose disconnected:
Mongoose connection error:MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
```

So I changed the second line of code that is in the db.js file to the code below

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/CaribbeanDb', {useNewUrlParser: true})
```

after the changes...  I now get this error below

```
Mongoose connection error:MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
```

I have tried to do further research to solve the error. I came across some commands which are below. to input into git terminal to solve the issue, but the commands are not found within the terminal.

```
$ sudo rm /data/db/mongod.lock
$ sudo mongod --dbpath /data/db/ --repair
$ sudo mongod --dbpath /data/db/ --journal
```

Any suggestions .. as I am running out of ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: Have you installed the MongoDB server on your local machine? Mongoose is not the server itself.

Comment: @ jonnyHk will attempt to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have MongoDB installed on your machine?

Mongoose is an ORM, while MongoDB is the actual database which makes it a dependency for Mongoose.

If you're on macOS, you can run:

```
mongo -version
```

If it spits back that you do not have it, install with Homebrew:

```
brew install mongo
sudo mkdir -p /data/db
sudo chown -R `id -un` /data/db
```

Start the MongoDB daemon:

```
mongod
```

Comment: great, all up and running now